# Calculate and rely on first and last group items in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My data structure

| detected_time | estimated_stay_time | is_frist_group | is_last_group | floor_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1700820829831 | 25000 | false | true | L2 |
| 1700820829546 | 25000 | true | false | L2 |
| 1700820080819 | 25000 | true | true | L2 |
| 1700819957178 | 35000 | false | true | L1 |
| 1700819956726 | 35000 | true | false | L1 |
| 1700819579652 | 35000 | true | true | L1 |
| 1700819377593 | 25000 | false | true | L2 |
| 1700819021697 | 25000 | false | false | L2 |
| 1700819019951 | 25000 | true | false | L2 |

I have grouped them into a data structure like this and have column frist_group to identify them as the first item of the group and last_group as the last item of the group

If rows frist_group and last_group are both true, then it is both item frist and last

You can see that they are grouped on consecutive floors. If they are interrupted by another floor, they will be recalculated

The output I want is calculated according to the formula

frist_group = true of the last group I call it FG

last_group = true of the first group I call it LG

estimated_stay_time of the last group item and the last item of that group, I call it ETM

FG - LG + ETM

Looking at the database structure, each group will be:

1700820829546 - 1700820080819 + 25000 = 773,727

1700819956726 - 1700819579652 + 35000 = 412,074

1700819019951 - 1700819019951 + 25000 = 25,000

How do i achieve the expected output? i use postgresql

output:

| detected_time | estimated_stay_time | frist_group | last_group | floor | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1700820829831 | 25000 | false | true | L2 | 773,727 |
| 1700820829546 | 25000 | true | false | L2 | null |
| 1700820080819 | 25000 | true | true | L2 | null |
| 1700819957178 | 35000 | false | true | L1 | 412,074 |
| 1700819956726 | 35000 | true | false | L1 | null |
| 1700819579652 | 35000 | true | true | L1 | null |
| 1700819377593 | 25000 | false | true | L2 | 25,000 |
| 1700819021697 | 25000 | false | false | L2 | null |
| 1700819019951 | 25000 | true | false | L2 | null |

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the db contents](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the db schema and its contents as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: Unless the content is inherently graphical, don't paste it or link to it as an image. The formula and output should be included in the post as formatted text. Also, please include the associated table DDL, SQL to populate the table with example data, and the queries you have attempted. Minimizing the effort required to explore the question will maximize the likelihood of a useful response.

Comment: The algorithm is absolutely not clear to me. Maybe you could make it a bit easier: Please take simpler numbers for the time column; the difference between "frist" and "first" confused my mind: is there a typo or maybe you could take better names; why can there be two elements with "frist" (first? in my mind, there's only one first, the earliest and one last, the latest...); please explain the calculation algorithm...